# awk keep on print only first line inside while loop unless echo, theory explanation

Tags: linux, bash, shell, loops, awk

I have an awk command that outputs the results from line-modification in a loop:

```sh
clinvar_db=$1
output_file=$2

if [ -f "$output_file" ]; then
  rm "$output_file"
fi

zcat < "$clinvar_db" | grep -v '^#' | while read line; do

  chr=`echo $line | awk '{print $1}' | tr -d '[:space:]'`
  pos=`echo $line | awk '{print $2}' | tr -d '[:space:]'`


  clnrevstat=`echo $line | sed -e 's/.*CLNREVSTAT=\(.*\);CLNSIG.*/\1/' | cut -d';' -f1`

  ref_all=`echo $line | awk '{print $4}' | tr -d '[:space:]'`
  alt_all=`echo $line | awk '{print $5}' | tr -d '[:space:]'`
  effect=`echo $line | sed -e 's/.*MC=\(.*\);.*/\1/' | cut -d';' -f1 | cut -d'|' -f2`
  ref_length=`printf $ref_all | wc -c | tr -d '[:space:]'`
  alt_length=`printf $alt_all | wc -c | tr -d '[:space:]'`
  if [ "$ref_length" -ne "$alt_length " ] || [ "$effect" == 'frameshift_variant' ] || [ "$effect" == 'nonsense' ] || [ "$effect" == 'splice_acceptor_variant' ] || [ "$effect" == 'splice_donor_variant' ]; then
    var_effect='lof'
  elif [ "$effect" == 'missense_variant' ]; then
    var_effect='miss'
  elif [ "$effect" == 'synonymous_variant' ]; then
    var_effect='syn'
  elif [ "$effect" == 'intron_variant' ] || [ "$effect" == '3_prime_UTR_variant' ]; then
    var_effect='intron'
  else
    var_effect='NA'
  fi

  if [ "$clnrevstat" == 'criteria_provided,_conflicting_interpretations' ] || [ "$clnrevstat" == 'criteria_provided,_single_submitter' ]; then
    clnstar=1
  elif [ "$clnrevstat" == 'no_assertion_criteria_provided' ] || [ "$clnrevstat" == 'no_assertion_provided' ] || [ "$clnrevstat" == 'no_interpretation_for_the_single_variant' ]; then
    clnstar=0
  elif [ "$clnrevstat" == 'criteria_provided,_multiple_submitters,_no_conflicts' ]; then
    clnstar=2
  elif [ "$clnrevstat" == 'reviewed_by_expert_panel' ]; then
    clnstar=3
  elif [ "$clnrevstat" == 'practice_guideline' ]; then
    clnstar=2
  else
    clnstar=NA
  fi

  awk -v OFS='\t' -v chr="$chr" -v pos="$pos" -v ref="$ref_all" -v alt="$alt_all" -v var_effect="$var_effect" -v clnstar="$clnstar" '{print chr,pos,".",ref,alt,".",".",".",var_effect,clnstar}'

done
```

this output the same (first) line over and over again:

```sh
1   949422  .   G   A   .   .   .   miss    1
1   949422  .   G   A   .   .   .   miss    1
1   949422  .   G   A   .   .   .   miss    1
1   949422  .   G   A   .   .   .   miss    1
1   949422  .   G   A   .   .   .   miss    1
1   949422  .   G   A   .   .   .   miss    1
1   949422  .   G   A   .   .   .   miss    1
# ...
```

if I add an `echo` before last `awk`

```sh
# ... rest of my script ...
  echo  | awk -v OFS='\t' -v chr="$chr" -v pos="$pos" -v ref="$ref_all" -v alt="$alt_all" -v var_effect="$var_effect" -v clnstar="$clnstar" '{print chr,pos,".",ref,alt,".",".",".",var_effect,clnstar}'
# ... rest of my script ...
```

OUTPUT:

```sh
1   949422  .   G   A   .   .   .   miss    1
1   949502  .   C   T   .   .   .   miss    1
1   949523  .   C   T   .   .   .   lof 0
1   949559  .   C   T   .   .   .   miss    1
1   949597  .   C   T   .   .   .   syn 1
1   949608  .   G   A   .   .   .   miss    1
1   949635  .   G   A   .   .   .   miss    1
1   949656  .   G   A   .   .   .   miss    1
1   949696  .   C   CG  .   .   .   lof 0
# ...
```

it resolves the problem, but I'd like to know from you expert guys why! It wouldn't be supposed to do it once per iteration? I've searched here and the web but I couldn't figure it out by myself...

Thanks a lot in advance for any help!

Comment: Because you shouldn't use shell loops to manipulate text as they're extremely hard to write robustly, extremely slow, often non-portable etc. I can see several bugs in your script at a glance (you might want to run it through shellcheck!). See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/133219. Whatever your shell script is doing would be much better as simply `zcat < "$clinvar_db" | awk 'whatever your grep | while... is doing'`.

Comment: that was helpful, I'm rewriting it in C++. Thanks @EdMorton

Comment: That makes no sense. Just do it in awk. The end result will be clearer, simpler, faster/easier to write/enhance/debug, more robust, and will probably run faster.

Answer (score 0):

When you invoke `awk` without the echo, it is reading from same pipe as the `while read` loop.  The while loop reads the first line, and awk reads all the rest.